# reuse moongoose connection in other files

Tags: node.js, mongoose, singleton

I realize mongoose is a singleton and once you do `mongoose.connect` in one file and later all scripts that require this file will have mongoose connected as well.

But shouldn't that mean when I execute another test script that only has `require('mongoose')` in it and it will show that I am connected to mongodb too because the previous script (which starts an http server) is still running and I am referencing the the same mongoose inside `node_modules`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Here is an example of a file: myLib.js inside my /lib directory

```
exports.someVar = [5,4,3,2,1];
exports.printSize = function(){
    console.log(exports.someVar.length);
}
```

Now let's create an other file named app.js and include the myLib.js:

```
var myLib = require("./lib/myLib.js");
var http = require("./http.js");

console.log("app.js:");
myLib.printSize(); // will print 5
myLib.someVar.push(100);
console.log("app.js:");
myLib.printSize(); // will print 6
console.log("calling http");
http.start();
console.log("app.js:");
myLib.printSize(); // will print 7
```

Okay, now let's create an other file, named `http.js` and include the myLib.js too:

```
var myLib = require("./lib/myLib.js");


exports.start = function(){
    console.log("http.js:");
    myLib.printSize(); // will print 6
    myLib.someVar.push(200);
}
```

Now lets create a project for myLib.js and replace all lines:

```
var myLib = require("./lib/myLib.js");
```

to:

```
var myLib = require("myLib");
```

And the result will be the same, that is the why the mongoose connection are active even when you use require("mongoose") in other parts of your project.

After you create a connection, the variable will be available for other parts of your project.

It is like a singleton, so you do not need create your own for hold the connection reference.

Comment: you mean create 3 files and app.js and http.js in turn?  I think when you run http.js the output is 5?